# Gaussian Progress Regression usecase

Tags: machine-learning, regression, gaussian, robotics, non-linear-regression

while reading the paper :" Tactile-based active object discrimination and target object search in an unknown workspace", there is something that I just can not understand:

The paper is about finding object's position and other properties using only tactile information. In the section 4.1.2, the author says that he uses GPR to guide the exploratory process and in section 4.1.4 he describes how he trained his GPR:

1. Using the example from the section 4.1.2, the input is (x,z) and the ouput y.
2. Whenever there is a contact, the coresponding y-value is stored.
3. This procedure is repeated several times.
4. This trained GPR is used to estimate the next exploring point, which is the point where the variance is maximum at.

In the following link, you also can see the demonstration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiLq3i-BJcA&t=177s . In the first part of video (0:24-0:29), the first initalization takes place where the robot samples 4 times. Then in the next 25 seconds, the robot explores explores from the corresponding direction. I do not understand how this tiny initialization of GPR can guide the exploratory process. Could someone please explain how the input points (x,z) from the first exploring part could be estimated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any regression algorithm simply maps the input `(x,z)` to an output `y` in some way unique to the specific algorithm. For a new input `(x0,z0)` the algorithm will likely predict something very close to the true output `y0` if many data points similar to this was included in the training. If only training data was available in a vastly different region, the predictions will likely be very bad.

GPR includes a measure of confidence of the predictions, namely the variance. The variance will naturally be very high in regions where no training data has been seen before and low very close to already seen data points. If the 'experiment' takes much longer than evaluating the Gaussian Process, you can use the Gaussian Process fit to make sure you sample regions where you are very uncertain of your answer.

If the goal is to fully explore the entire input space, you could draw a lot of random values of `(x,z)` and evaluate the variance at these values. Then you could perform the costly experiment at the input point where you are most uncertain in `y`. Then you can retrain the GPR with all the explored data so far and repeat the process.

**For optimization problems (Not the OP's question)**

If you wish to find the lowest value of `y` across the input space, you are not interested in doing the experiment in regions that you know give high values of `y`, but you are just uncertain of *how* high these values will be. So instead of choosing the `(x,z)` points with the highest variance, you might choose the predicted value of `y` plus one standard deviation. Minimizing values this way is named Bayesian Optimization and this specific scheme is named Upper Confidence Bound (UCB). Expected Improvement (EI) - the probability of improving the previously best score - is also commonly used.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the method from the paper utilizes the fact that the regions where the robot has not been there in the training/exploring phase has higher variance value and lead the robot to those regions.

Comment: Then disregard the last half of the last paragraph (See edit). I included that for completion.

Comment: Sorry for asking an additional Question, but what if my Goal is to check the environment from the training is simliar as now. So after training I will have a GPR model which I trained with multiple (x,z) points and corresponding to the environment the training label (Output ) y will be estimated. How could I lead the robot afterwards? By giving a new Point (x1,z1), I could check with (y1-y) the deviation, but could I somehow do this in a more systematical way using variance for example?

Comment: For a given new point `(x1,z1)` your GP will output the expected variance. If you evaluate the variance of say 1000 random points this way, you can choose to do the actual experiment on the point the GP expects to have the largest variance (then retrain, get the next point etc.). The variance is predicted by the GP so you don't have to do additional experiments to estimate this. Not to be confused with the variance between your predictions and experiment outcomes.

Comment: In the case that I described in the above comment, the GPR_1 is trained in the environment_1. And in the environment_2 I want to measure how different these environments are. If I evaluate the variance of the point (x2,z2) from the environement_2 with GPR_1, I could automatically measure the difference between these two environment. But for example when I retrain the GPR_1 for the next point (x2,z2)_2 , the GPR_1 will be changed (my reference environment model gets changed). Or it doesnt matter since I am just observing the max_variances with GPR_1 and points (x2,z2).

Comment: If I understand correctly there are two distinct cases. 1) You are exploring both environments. 2) You have already explored `environment_1` and are now exploring `environment_2`. In 1) you would only fit one GP to the difference between the outputs from both experiments from the same input. In 2) you would fit a GP or other regression algorithm to the inputs and outputs of the first experiment (call this `R1`), then train a GP on the difference between the output of the second experiment and the output from `R1`. In both cases you would explore inputs with the largest GP variance.